# How to automatically add protocol to incomplete URL?

Tags: forms, validation, urls

The user must fill in the url for the correct functionality of the system, including protocol (http or https). In the most cases, user pastes URL with protocol.
Less often pastes URL without protocol or types URL manually. Here we of course can show error message. But I am trying to find more elegant solution. For example some UI element, where user can simple choose which protocol wants. Something like autocomplete with both options?
Do you have some recommendation for me? Thanks

Comment: Some similar comments and suggestions in this question may be of help: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9169/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-let-a-user-add-a-url-to-a-form/103069#103069

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would be the best way to let a user add a URL to a form?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9169/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-let-a-user-add-a-url-to-a-form)

Answer (score 1):

**Do you have some recommendation for me?**

In the best case, the user does not have to make that choice and your system recognizes which protocol is used after he entered the url.

If that is technically not possible then something like this will work:

[image]

Preselect the option that gets used the most.
Add an info-option for users that arent so tech-savvy.

Comment: Thanks, definitely usable solution. I just wonder about users who just want to paste the URL with the protocol. Whether they are a little bit confused by 2 UI elements.

Comment: Of course, they should be able to past whole URL to "Your website e.g..." input field and then we can split URL. But do they know it?

Comment: why would they care about the protocol?
You can convert the pasted url from https://www.example.com to a Dropdown which displays http and the url that displays as www.example.com